# PDFMiner TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdfminer

I have been trying to come up with a solution to parse a PDF into an HTML so, later I'll use beautiful soup to extract all the headings, subitems and paragraph respectively in a tree structure.

I have searched a few options available on the internet but so far no success. Here's a code I've used to parse a PDF to HTML using **PDFMiner.six**

```
import sys
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.layout import LTContainer, LTComponent, LTRect, LTLine, LAParams, LTTextLine
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfdevice import PDFDevice, TagExtractor
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.converter import XMLConverter, HTMLConverter, TextConverter
from pdfminer.image import ImageWriter
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import io



def convert_pdf_to_html(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    outfp = BytesIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = HTMLConverter(rsrcmgr, outfp, imagewriter=ImageWriter('out'))
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device) 
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0 #is for all
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    str = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return str

convert_pdf_to_html('PDF - Remraam Ph 1 Mosque.pdf')
```

However, the above code returns the following error which I'm unable to fix, would appreciate any help, thank you.

```
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdftypes.py in decode(self)
    293                 data = ccittfaxdecode(data, params)
    294             elif f == LITERAL_CRYPT:
--> 295                 raise PDFNotImplementedError('Crypt filter is unsupported')
    296             else:
    297                 raise PDFNotImplementedError('Unsupported filter: %r' % f)

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Exact duplicat of [pdf-to-html-parsing-in-python-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080975/pdf-to-html-parsing-in-python-3), consider to delete this or the other.

Answer (score -1):

The pdfminer.six package does not support pdf's with a Crypt filter. It does support other encryption methods. The difference with the Crypt filter is that this one defines the decription algorithm as a parameters, instead of a fixed filter.

From the Pdf reference manual:

> The Crypt filter (PDF 1.5) allows the document-level security handler (see Section 3.5, “Encryption”) to determine which algorithms should be used to decrypt the input data. The Name parameter in the decode parameters dictionary for this
>   filter (see Table 3.12) specifies which of the named crypt filters in the document
>   (see Section 3.5.4, “Crypt Filters”) should be used.

If you need this feature you can create a [github issue](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/issues).

Answer (score -1):

A quick update, I have fixed this issue, by just uninstalling and installing the Anaconda and then I've installed the pdfminer.six by coda. I guess the pip install doesn't work properly for me. Any way install the package using coda install .. package name